# Maven Plugin to automatically generate setters/getters?

Tags: java, maven-2, plugins

Is there a Maven Plugin that will automatically generate setters and getters with the corresponding JavaDocs?

I am aware that Eclipse/Netbeans  will do this when you tell it to; however, it would be nice for the source to simply contain the skeleton and have Maven or another tool generate the repetitive stuff.

I would want to modify the source code so that a source jar can be compiled and used when debugging.

Thanks,
Walter

Answer (score 5):

This isn't necessarily something that you want maven to do for you.  It will make working with the code in the IDE harder, as the IDE won't necessarily know about the generated code unless it has a plugin that understands Lombok's notation. IntelliJ has such a [plugin](https://code.google.com/p/lombok-intellij-plugin/)  available.

That said, [project lombok](http://projectlombok.org/) aims to do this properly through the use of an `@Data` annotation.  It looks like it works well, but I haven't tried it.  It supports a number of environments and IDEs through plugins, including Maven, Eclipse, IntelliJ and Netbeans. There are a few caveats with Netbeans currently, see the project documentation.

Comment: Lombok does offer a de-lombok option to generate java code without any reference to Lombok, to make working with other IDE's and some frameworks easier.

Comment: Lombok supports NetBeansm, and reportedly also JDeveloper. IDEA support is currently still missing.

Comment: The [lombok-maven-plugin](http://awhitford.github.com/lombok.maven/lombok-maven-plugin/) may be of interest.  As long as the IDE supports Maven, you should be good with it.

Comment: I am using photon eclipse jee and org.projectlombok is present in the pom.xml with a version of 1.6.6, still the getter and setter methods give a problem....How do I get over this?

Answer (score 1):

You could try [Modello](http://modello.codehaus.org/), it allows you to specify a model and let the java be generated during the build by the [modello-maven-plugin](http://modello.codehaus.org/modello-maven-plugin/index.html).

Answer (score 1):

I know you asked for a Maven plugin but there is annotation based project that takes care of many boilerplate code issues in Java:

http://projectlombok.org

Answer (score 0):

There is a use case that doesn't work with Eclipse and the mouse.
Sometimes you need accessors in generated Java files, say, from an IDL specification.
One example would be if the classes are further processed by an ORM framework.

Now, how can this easily be done with Maven?
Of course, it's possible to script it or use the replacer plugin; but is there any off-the-shelf solution?